# Room: Renaming Table doesn't update Foreign Key Table Reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

```
object Migration1to2 : Migration(1, 2) {

    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE photos RENAME TO media")
    }
}
```

I'm using the above Migration object to perform the migration but get the following `IllegalStateException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle tags(com.curator.android.storage.room.model.Tag).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='tags', columns={groupId=Column{name='groupId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, photoId=Column{name='photoId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, accuracy=Column{name='accuracy', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, entityId=Column{name='entityId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}, parentId=Column{name='parentId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='media', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[photoId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_tags_photoId', unique=false, columns=[photoId]}, Index{name='index_tags_name_photoId', unique=true, columns=[name, photoId]}, Index{name='index_tags_name', unique=false, columns=[name]}]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='tags', columns={groupId=Column{name='groupId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, photoId=Column{name='photoId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, accuracy=Column{name='accuracy', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, entityId=Column{name='entityId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}, parentId=Column{name='parentId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='photos', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[photoId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_tags_photoId', unique=false, columns=[photoId]}, Index{name='index_tags_name_photoId', unique=true, columns=[name, photoId]}, Index{name='index_tags_name', unique=false, columns=[name]}]}
```

The difference is between the referenceTable

```
foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='media', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[photoId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}]
foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='photos', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[photoId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQLite There is only a limited support for foreign keys [1]. If you really want to rename the table you have to create a new table with updated foreign keys and copy the content of the old table. (Adjusted from [2])

```
object Migration1to2 : Migration(1, 2) {

    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;")
        database.beginTransaction()
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE photos RENAME TO media; ")
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tags RENAME TO tagsOld; ")
        // database.execSQL("DROP INDEX `indexName`") // optional
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `tags` ( ... ); ") // you can copy that from scheme 2.json
        // database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX `indexName` ON `tags` ( ... )") // optional - you can copy that from scheme 2.json
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO tags SELECT * FROM tagsOld; ")
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE tagsOld; ")
        database.setTransactionSuccessful()
        database.endTransaction()
        database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;")
    }
}
```

[1] https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

[2] https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/foreign_keys/drop.php

Comment: Hm. Strange. I copied the db file to PC and connected to it using DBeaver. Then I renamed the table in SQL editor by running `alter table x rename to y`. All the dependent tables switched their references accordingly. It looks like room has problems with that command and not SQLite...

Comment: Your approach seems to work. Thanks. However any migration is a challenge even without this and if you have to apply such workarounds it becomes a nightmare. It seems that you'll have to recreate all the referenced tables etc.